# Who are the real parents of Sita?

Tags: ramayana

I am still confuse about Sita's Mother and Father. I listen she born from earth, also She is the daughter of Ravan.

I am reaching to be around 40 years being a Hindu, still if someone asks this to me I unable answer.

Who are the real father and mother of Sita?

Comment: Sita didn't take birth from womb of any woman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his Complete Works, V4, lecture "The Ramayana", Swami Vivekananda says  (available here - http://www.advaitaashrama.org/cw/content.php):

> Now, there was another king, called Janaka, and this king had a beautiful daughter named Sitâ. Sita was found in a field; she was a daughter of the Earth, and was born without parents. The word "Sita" in ancient Sanskrit means the furrow made by a plough. In the ancient mythology of India you will find persons born of one parent only, or persons born without parents, born of sacrificial fire, born in the field, and so on — dropped from the clouds as it were. All those sorts of miraculous birth were common in the mythological lore of India.